# combine 2 or more in operator in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to select rows from a data frame according to some conditions. I usually select values using `% in %` operator. I used many `%in%` for selecting values.

```
  val1 <- portData [portData$PmkVal %in% c(NA),]
  val2 <- val1 [val1$Quantity %in% c(NA),]
  weigtageData <- val2 [val2$MktVal %in% c(NA),]
```

Can i write all these statements in one line and select data from frame `portData` itself instead of writing this inefficient code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to remove NA in variables `PmkVal` and `Quality` in `portData`? How about `portData[is.na(portData$PmkVal) & is.na(portData$Quality) & is.na(portData%MktVal), ]`?

Comment: waaw,..thats a good idea..thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First since you're checking for `NA`, you can use the nice handy function `is.na(.)`. That is,

```
val1 <- portData [is.na(portData$PmkVal), ]
val2 <- val1[is.na(val1$Quantity), ]
weigtageData <- val2[is.na(val2$MktVal), ]
```

---

Now, you can use `&` to connect all these together in a single command as follows:

```
weigtageDate <- portData[is.na(portData$PmkVal) & 
                         is.na(portData$Quantity) & 
                         is.na(portData$MktVal), ]
```

---

Even nicer is to use `with` here, so that you dont have to use `portData$` every time.

```
weigtageData <- portData[with(portData, is.na(PmkVal) & 
                           is.na(Quantity) & is.na(MktVal)), ]
```

Of course the same translates to `%in%` as well. It's just not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

One other option would be to use the `complete.cases` function if you check for NA's:

```
test <- matrix(sample(20),ncol=5)
colnames(test) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

test[2,1] <- NA
test[3,1] <- NA
test[4,2] <- NA

test[complete.cases(test),]
test[complete.cases(test[,2]),]
test[complete.cases(test[,c(1,2)]),]
```

EDIT: In order to keep only rows with missing values inside, you have to invert the call via `!` like:

```
test[!complete.cases(test),]
```

Comment: This is nice, however, you may want to *negate* the output. OP wants *to keep* the columns with NA in them.